# SQL Server installation fails with 'NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY' account error

Tags: sql-server, installation

I'm trying to install Microsoft SQL Server 2019. If I perform the installation interactively, the installation completes successfully. But if I use the configuration file created by this successful installation, and do the installation non-interactively (via the command `E:\setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=xxxxx`), this installation fails with:

> The following error occurred:
> Virtual Account 'NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY' provided for 'NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER1' is either not a valid account or cannot be used for this service.
>
> Error result: -2068578304
> Result facility code: 1204
> Result error code: 0

I'm assuming that the interactive execution has the privileges to create this `NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY` account, but the non-interactive execution does not?

Any thoughts on how to get the non-interactive execution to work? My end-game is to automate the SQL Server execution using the Ansible `win_package module`.

Thanks for the help!

I tried the non-interactive execution, using the configuration file produced by the interactive execution, and had expected this non-interactive execution to successfully install SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the silent installation via command line, you'll want to run the cmd or powershell terminal as Administrator. In order to do this, your user needs to have Administrator privileges on the machine. Right click the app (whatever terminal you're using), then click "Run as Administrator" if it is listed and "More" if it isn't.

To achieve the same thing with ansible, you'll need to set the become_method and become_user variables and then set become to true. I elect to set the method and user at the playbook level, and the become var at the task level so that I don't have to set it to false on each task that I do not want to run as Administrator.

```
---
- name: Install and configure sqlserver 2019
  hosts: sqlserver
  become_method: runas
  become_user: Administrator
  tasks:
    - name: Execute installation media
      win_package:
        path: 'E:\setup.exe'
        arguments: "/ConfigurationFile=xxxxx"
        state: present
      become: true
```

Using the configuration file, as is, from an interactive installation won't be enough to install silently. You'll have to add/update a few values in either the configuration file or the command line arguments. I'm listing what I see in my own file below, but check out the whole [list of options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"
PID="<your_license or the developer id 22222-00000-00000-00000-00000>"
QUIET="True"
QUIETSIMPLE="False"
SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="False"
SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE="True"
INDICATEPROGRESS="False"
SAPWD="<some_password>"
SQLSVCPASSWORD="<some_password>"
```

Edit: Here is my entire ConfigurationFile.ini in case there is another value that is allowing the creation of the telemetry user. You'll have to update the values for your hostname and sa user passwords. Overall, silent installs are not usually difficult but sometimes finding the right combination of variables and permissions can be annoying.

```
;SQL Server 2019 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

ACTION="Install"
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"
IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS="False"
IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS="False"
PID="22222-00000-00000-00000-00000"

QUIET="True"
QUIETSIMPLE="False"
SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="False"
SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE="True"
INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

UpdateSource="MU"
UpdateEnabled="False"
USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="False"
HELP="False"

FEATURES=SQLENGINE,CONN,IS,BC
INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER"
INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER"
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="your-servers-hostname\Administrator"
SAPWD="desired-sa-password"

ENU="True"
SQLMAXDOP="4"
SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="True"
SECURITYMODE="SQL"
SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT="4"
SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE="8"
SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH="64"
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE="8"
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH="64"
TCPENABLED="1"
NPENABLED="1"
USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS="True"

SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQLSERVER"
SQLSVCPASSWORD="desired-sa-password"

SQLTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY"
SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
ISTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SSISTELEMETRY150"

AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT"
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
ISSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MsDtsServer150"

COMMFABRICPORT="0"
COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"
COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"
MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"

X86="False"
FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"
ENABLERANU="False"
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="False"
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
```

Comment: Hi Danielle - thanks very much for your fast and informative answer! I very much appreciate your help. Reading what you wrote, it certainly had the 'ring of truth' to me.

Comment: So, I created a Windows Command Prompt window by selecting the 'Run as administrator' option, and ran the setup.exe command in that window. So I was surprised to see that the setup.exe execution failed with the same error as I reported in my base posting.

A 'net user' administrator' output shows, in part:
Local Group Memberships      *Administrators

So I'm not sure why setup.exe is still failing.  Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `SQLTELSVCACCT` in your ConfigurationFile.ini?

Comment: ; TelemetryUserNameConfigDescription 

SQLTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY"

; TelemetryStartupConfigDescription 

SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

Comment: I'm just throwing darts at this point, I thought surely not running as admin was the issue. My next approach would be to try using the minimum variables, either passed directly at the command line or in a config file, to install from the cmd line. If you look at the documentation for installing from the cmd line, they pass in very few in the examples. Then you can bit by bit work in your customizations. Maybe it'll turn out that some fluff was causing a weird issue or that there were two vars that cannot be set together.

Comment: Hi Danielle - thanks very much for sharing this idea! Late last week, I decided the same thing. I've found that creating a MS SQL Server configuration file from an installation run, modifying it to run silently and executing setup.exe silently does not work. I believe there is something toxic in the combination of the generated-then-modified  configuration file plus setup.exe. Trying to figure out which combination of the dozens of configuration file parameters seemed a huge time sink. So I abandoned that approach.

Comment: Instead, through trail and I error, I found the truly required setup.exe options. Here is that setup.exe command, in Ansible task:

name: Install Microsoft SQL Server from mounted iso
  win_shell: "{{ disk_image_out.mount_paths[0] }}setup.exe  /QUIET /ACTION=Install /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /INSTANCENAME={{ instance }} /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=\"BUILTIN\\Administrators\" /UPDATEENABLED=False"
  args:
    executable: cmd
  register: sql_install_out
  when: sql_service.exists == False

Comment: NOTE that the above will not work unless the fix in https://eugenechiang.com/2019/04/24/sql-server-setup-error-there-was-an-error-generating-the-xml-document-error-code-0x84b10001/ is implemented.

Comment: Are you using an older windows or sqlserver version? I haven't encountered the xml issue. I've got all of those variables in the above list though. Glad you got it worked out!

Comment: Hi Danielle - I'm installing Microsoft SQL Server 2019 on Windows Server 2022.